# Postgresql updating query based on join

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table I created on a simple join.  I have tried this many different ways and am still getting errors.  Any help is appericated

```
Update well.formation_assignments as v
set
Primary_Formation = well.geo.primary_formation
from well.geo as s
inner join 
 on well.formation_assignments.api14=well.geo.api14;
```

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "on"
LINE 6:  on well.formation_assignments.api14=well.geo.api14;
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
UPDATE well.formation_assignments v
SET Primary_Formation = s.primary_formation
FROM well.geo s
WHERE v.api14 = s.api14;
```

As standard Postgresql update syntax is as follows :

```
[ WITH [ RECURSIVE ] with_query [, ...] ]
UPDATE [ ONLY ] table [ [ AS ] alias ]
    SET { column = { expression | DEFAULT } |
          ( column [, ...] ) = ( { expression | DEFAULT } [, ...] ) } [, ...]
    [ FROM from_list ]
    [ WHERE condition | WHERE CURRENT OF cursor_name ]
    [ RETURNING * | output_expression [ [ AS ] output_name ] [, ...] ]
```

Documentation : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-update.html

Comment: Thank you I will try it.  I appreciate your time